# Using sys.stdin

Tags: python, python-3.x, cmd

For the `input.txt` like below:

```
red#
12 34#
abcd ef ghijk#
```

I want to get the `output.txt`, removing `'#'` like:

```
red
12 34
abcd ef ghijk
```

What I did:

```
import sys
line = sys.stdin.readline()
while line:
    line = line.rstrip("#")
    print(line)
    line = sys.stdin.readline()
```

Comment: please edit the question.

Comment: Your lines will end with a newline character (except maybe the very last one in the file).  You'd need to strip that off before the `#` would be seen by `.rstrip()` - you could strip both at once with `.rstrip("\n#")`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the context manager below:

```
with open('input.txt', 'r') as r:
    file = r.read().splitlines()

file = [line.rstrip('#') for line in file]

with open('output.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write('\n'.join(file))
```

If you are certain that the hashtags only apear at the end of the lines, you can also use the `str.replace()` method:

```
with open('input.txt', 'r') as r:
    file = r.read().replace('#', '')

with open('output.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(file)
```